# didUpdateLocations: method not called on device running iOS 7

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am facing a strange problem. I am using 
`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` to get device location. It is working fine on `simulator (iOS 6 and iOS 7)` and `iPhone 4S running iOS 6.1.3`. It is also working fine when I connect `iPhone 4 running iOS 7` to system and install the app but as soon as I unplug the device and re-run the app, this method doesn't get called and I don't get the location. How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How did you setup you location Manager?

Do you have in your interface:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    @property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
```

Then in implementation in viewDidLoad:

```
// setup location manager
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        _locationManager.delegate = self;

        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

And you need to implement the delegate:

```
locationManager:didUpdateLocations:
```

Be careful: In IOS 7

```
locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation
```

is deprecated.
[Apple link to CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateLocations%3a)

Comment: `headingAvailable` is deprecated since `iOS 4` and I'm using `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`

Comment: a..sorry. headingAvailable doesn't fit in (copy paste mistake). But anyways. headingAvailable property was deprecated. This is a call to recommended +(BOOL)headingAvailable (i changed it to locationServicesEnabled).
Interesting that it does't work. Have you tried changing to _locationbManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; ? That should notify delegate of all movements.

Comment: I've exactly the same code as yours apart from the `if` condition.

Comment: I've created a simple project and it works for me (iPhone 5, iOS 7.0.4) as well on the simulators: git@github.com:rendulic/CLLocationTest.git

Comment: Thanks for your time, your code is working fine and the strange thing is that my code is also working today, tho I didn't change anything whatsoever

Comment: No problem. I've noticed some problems in simulators when geo location is in question. Not yet on a device. Anyhow. Its working :)

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct until someone comes up with more precise answer to this problem.